# Is a loop function a solution to this problem

Tags: python, pymupdf

I have the following code, taken and adapted from the [Collection of Recipes of PyMuPdf](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-to-mark-searched-text).

```
import fitz

# the document to annotate
doc = fitz.open("test3.pdf")

# the text to be marked
t = "lidiar con estas problemáticas"

# work with first page only
page = doc[0]

# get list of text locations
# we use "quads", not rectangles because text may be tilted!

rl = page.search_for(t, quads = True)

# mark all found quads with one annotation
page.add_highlight_annot(rl)

# save to a new PDF
doc.save("test3_anotado.pdf")
```

I would like for `t` to be a list of different texts, and that the function `page.search_for` iterates through each element. I have read through fora on loops and while and so on---but I can't really get my head around how to approach the issue (needless to say, I am not well versed in python). I reckon it may have an easy, simple solution.

Potential use of this code: to highlight a PDF based on the annotations extracted from an ebook.

Comment: Yes, for loop would be one of the solutions for doing same set of tasks for different piece of data.

Comment: When you say: `t to be a list of different texts`, can you give an example of some `different texts`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a simple `for` loop:

```
import fitz

doc = fitz.open("test3.pdf")

# a list of text to be marked
text_list = ["lidiar con estas problemáticas", "random text", "more random text"]

page = doc[0]

# iterate through each text using for loop and annotate
for text in text_list:
    rl = page.search_for(text, quads = True)
    page.add_highlight_annot(rl)

# save to a new PDF at the end after annotating everything
doc.save("test3_anotado.pdf")
```

Answer (score 0):

Not used this library myself but assume this would work

```
import fitz

# the document to annotate
doc = fitz.open("test3.pdf")

# the text to be marked
texts = ["lidiar con estas problemáticas","this extra text","this other text"]

# work with first page only
page = doc[0]

# get list of text locations
# we use "quads", not rectangles because text may be tilted!
for t in texts:
    rl = page.search_for(t, quads = True)

# mark all found quads with one annotation
    page.add_highlight_annot(rl)

# save to a new PDF
doc.save("test3_anotado.pdf")
```

Literally just change t to a list of texts then added in a for loop to go over these and use the "search_for" function and then add_highlight_annot